# How to increase test run speed in VS Test Project?

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, load-testing

I'm trying to create a load test in VS Test Project. I have one empty test method which is called multiple times. At best my test runs 600 times per second.

How to increase the number of running tests per sec?

Comment: How do you call the test multiple times?

Comment: I setup Run Duration in timing settings of test.

Comment: @MitchWheat How faster could you make an empty test method?

Comment: @shtriha So, you use Load Tests, aren't you? If yes, retag tour question and add `Load-Testing` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At best my test runs 600 times per second.

I think this is limited by the machine where the `Load test` is executing. Perhaps, you can increase this number by:

- adding more `Virtual Users` to your Load Test. Your test iterations will be shared to the virtual users and they will be executing them in parallel.
- adding more `Test Agents`. If you are using a test rig for your `Load Tests` you can define more VM (if possible) as Test Agents.

See the following references for more details:

1. [Configuring Test Controllers and Test Agents for Load Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243155.aspx)
2. [About the Mix Control for Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243157.aspx)
3. [How to: Create a Test Setting for a Distributed Load Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426235.aspx)

**If you add functionality to your empty test method I am afraid the runs/sec number will decreased again.

Comment: Thank you. Most likely it's impossible to achieve good performance on one local machine.

Comment: Yes, except from the hardware, in your local machine are running both the Test Agent and the Test Controller which is responsible for collecting the Data and Diagnostics (see link 3). So this will limit the performance